# How to get money when using regtest

Tags: regtest

I want to experiment in the regtest network.
But I don't understand how I can get funds to play with.
I did:

`bitcoind -regtest -daemon`

`bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress 2N3V4PeQXoD6TFM9ZvDMX81kzbuNtc5YPW4 1`

and get:

`error code: -6
error message:
Insufficient funds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate some blocks.

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
```

You will have them in your wallet and can use the funds once confirmed. `101` is the number of blocks to create.
You can use any integer that's at least `101` as the number of blocks.
You cannot use a smaller integer than `101` if you want to test transactions, because of the [100 block maturation time](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/what-is-the-block-maturation-time/1992#1992).

Comment: Thanks! hmm that's odd. Before I tried generating 5 blocks, and it didn't allow me to spend. But with 101 it worked. Do you understand why?

Comment: @relG: It's because of the [100 block maturation time](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/1992/5757).