# Coinbase transaction UTXOs are prohibited until 100 confirmed? By what?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, locktime

I notice that many coinbase transactions(like in block 720,815) with locktime=0x00000000 and sequence=0xFFFFFFFF, which means UTXO could be spent immediately.
There seems to be no limit to coinbase's immediate use.

Comment: duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/what-is-the-block-maturation-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the block maturation time?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/what-is-the-block-maturation-time)

Comment: I know there is a block maturation time, i just don't understand how to implement it? when nodes verify UTXO, is there extra step to verify coinbase UTXO height ?  why don't just use CLTV or CSV ?

Comment: Coinbase maturity is verified here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L182